# Spark cache sorted dataset for sort merge join

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i have a data set which i join with multiple datasets. i have cached the dataset so that i don't have to reload data with each join.

But each join triggers sort phase which takes signifiant time. Is it possible to cache sorted dataset? so that explicit sorting is not needed before every join? Also cached join is taking longer than uncached data join, is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark sort data within partition because it use the `SortMergeJoin` algorithm, thats why you see a sort before every join.

Here is an example

I not sure it work, but to avoid sorting, you should at least:
repartition the data by the joining key, sort it then cache it. also the joining key in dataframes should have the same type.

```
dataset = dateset
.repartition(new Column("columnToJoinOn"))
.sortWithinPartitions(new Column("columnToJoinOn"))
.cache()
```

You can also use `explain()` methode to compare execution plan before and after modification

caching data can take longer time that read it from scrtach, it depend of lot of parameter. data size, source, transformations, cache strategy, disk I/O ...

you should take a look at `broadcastJoin`, that can maybe help you if your multiple dataframe are small enough.

Comment: as said i have huge dataset, hence broadcast is not possible

Comment: thanks for mentioning `sort data within partition`. i have added sample code. please review

Comment: you can try it, you should also use explain method to compare execution plan.